# PiCamera and Schedule is not working together

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, scheduled-tasks, picamera

i'm a bloddy starter at programming python and don't know, what i'm doing wrong. Im reading trough the documantaions from PiCamera and Schedule, but a combinded command is not working.

So i want to do this with schedule:

```
schedule.every().day.at("17:20:30").do(Foto).until("17:21:30")
```

which is working, when the job is: print.("bla")

and i want to this with PiCamera:

```
camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(2)
for filename in camera.capture_continuous('img{counter:03d}.jpg'):
    print('Captured %s' % filename)
    sleep(300) # wait 5 minutes
```

which is also working, in its own script. (copied by documentation)

But when i put them together:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
import schedule


def Foto():
camera = PiCamera() 
camera.start_preview()
sleep(2)
for filename in camera.capture_continuous('img{counter:03d}.jpg'):
    print('Captured %s' % filename)
    sleep(5) # wait 5 Sek

    
schedule.every().day.at("17:20:00").do(Foto).until("17:21:00")

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (moste recent call last):
File "usr/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 50, in parse
return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
File "home/pi/Dokumente/Schedule.py", line 9
camera = PiCamera()
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

i also tried to put `camera = PiCamera()` before `import schedule` which resulted in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "/home/pi/Dokumente/Schedule.py", line 11
    camera.start_preview()
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I hope you can help me :)

Ps. Here are the two docs:

https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#run-a-job-until-a-certain-time

https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes1.html#capturing-timelapse-sequences

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code of the function Foto is not *indented*.

```
def Foto():
    camera = PiCamera() 
    camera.start_preview()
    sleep(2)
    for filename in camera.capture_continuous('img{counter:03d}.jpg'):
        print('Captured %s' % filename)
        sleep(5) # wait 5 Sek
```